# How can I paint only graph area in echart, not axis label

Tags: javascript, echarts

[image]

I am implementing this screen with echart library ㅠ_ㅠ

```js
var option = { backgroundColor:"#fff"
```

This echart background color option makes the entire Grid white like this.
[image]

But how can I make only the numbered areas white?

I can't figure it out, GPT didn't answer the right question.

Comment: you want to remove the gridlines or remove the y-axis labels ?

Comment: @Kaneki21 No, I just want to set the background color of grid!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure which area should be affected. You can use `grid: {show: true, backgroundColor: <color>}` to set the background color of the grid.

Otherwise you could experiment with [rich text](https://echarts.apache.org/en/tutorial.html#Rich%20Text).

Here is a small [example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWsBGBDAxgawHMAnYAV2gBMBhYAG2CIC5YByBraAgUxYBo1YxCBWap06AM4ALYAHdmYIqS79xmXIRLlqdBsxa0IBKWGJcu0FgIC-q2AA8AgvYgTRA9GACeILvpxYYFwEDF58HrAUgVjMANosALIwfKwAKsopLADqXBSZqVKkmQBiRBCZAMqBleQsALp26FguEgAyWBhctO5q6Nj4xGSUNPRMrBi0GRHWNnZezq494t6--gBuWJM8jbDNru2d3cgR6ABmDAC2gUFjABQbWwCUCAB8rEhYAD4ssADUsA9lH9WNZwr1YGUcFIluCYsdwWp-pohjpRvovF16LIwQj0FIuEYTMwAIwATgA7DtwbJhGBobAAMwABhO4hm4PZbNmAgkXDKXDcsFiETEvSiYDhsWJAFYmbxYAAmZnyhUKgAsKuJAA55cSGdLdWrKYqAGxMhqslZ-ViGaDbaYCOooawAbiAA).